# merge dataframes and calculate one divided by the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
    concatted  score       date status  apple  banana  orange
0  apple_bana  0.500 2010-02-20   high   True   False   False
1       apple  0.400 2010-02-10   high   True   False   False
2      banana  0.530 2010-01-12   high  False    True   False
3        kiwi  0.532 2010-03-03    low  False   False   False
4        cake  0.634 2010-03-05    low  False   False   False 


fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
for fruit in fruits:
    df['fruit'] = df['concatted'].str.contains(fruit, regex=True)
df1=df.groupby('date')['status'].apply(lambda x: (x=='high').sum()).reset_index(name='count')
df2 = df['date'].value_counts().sort_index().reset_index(name='total')
```

How could I add df1 and df2 to the original df and calculate df1/df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data does not appear to show any features for really testing calcs.  Given that you want everything back in your original Dataframe `transform()` is your friend
Also changed way list is used to do reg expr `contains()` check to eliminate loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"concatted":["apple_bana","apple","banana","kiwi","cake"],"score":[0.5,0.4,0.53,0.532,0.634],"date":["2010-02-19T16:00:00.000Z","2010-02-09T16:00:00.000Z","2010-01-11T16:00:00.000Z","2010-03-02T16:00:00.000Z","2010-03-04T16:00:00.000Z"],"status":["high","high","high","low","low"],"fruit":[False,False,False,False,False]})

fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
df["fruit"] = df["concatted"].str.contains("|".join(fruits))
df["highcalc"] = df.groupby('date')['status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='high').sum())
df["datecount"] = df.groupby('date')["date"].transform("count")
df["finalcalc"] = df.apply(lambda r: r["highcalc"]/r["datecount"], axis=1 )
print(df.to_string(index=False))
df
```

**output**

```
  concatted  score                      date status  fruit  highcalc  datecount  finalcalc
 apple_bana  0.500  2010-02-19T16:00:00.000Z   high   True         1          1        1.0
      apple  0.400  2010-02-09T16:00:00.000Z   high   True         1          1        1.0
     banana  0.530  2010-01-11T16:00:00.000Z   high   True         1          1        1.0
       kiwi  0.532  2010-03-02T16:00:00.000Z    low  False         0          1        0.0
       cake  0.634  2010-03-04T16:00:00.000Z    low  False         0          1        0.0
```

**supplemental with columns to categorise rows**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"concatted":["apple_bana","apple","banana","kiwi","cake"],"score":[0.5,0.4,0.53,0.532,0.634],"date":["2010-02-19T16:00:00.000Z","2010-02-09T16:00:00.000Z","2010-01-11T16:00:00.000Z","2010-03-02T16:00:00.000Z","2010-03-04T16:00:00.000Z"],"status":["high","high","high","low","low"]})

df["highcalc"] = df.groupby('date')['status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='high').sum())
df["datecount"] = df.groupby('date')["date"].transform("count")
df["finalcalc"] = df.apply(lambda r: r["highcalc"]/r["datecount"], axis=1 )

dfcat = pd.DataFrame({"concatted":df["concatted"].unique(), "cat":np.NaN, "truth":True})
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
bakery = ["cake"]
dfcat.loc[dfcat["cat"].isna() & dfcat["concatted"].str.contains("|".join(fruits)), "cat"] = "fruit"
dfcat.loc[dfcat["cat"].isna() & dfcat["concatted"].str.contains("|".join(bakery)), "cat"] = "bakery"
dfcat = dfcat.fillna("tbd")
dfcat["internal"] = dfcat["cat"] + "_" + dfcat["concatted"]
dfcat["col"] = dfcat.internal.str.split("_")
dfcat = dfcat.explode("col").drop("internal", 1)

dfcat = dfcat.pivot(index="concatted", columns="col", values="truth").reset_index().fillna(False)
df.merge(dfcat, on=["concatted"])
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do this if I had multiple criteria? i.e. i have columns for apple, banana and orange which show as True if that fruit appears in the column concatted

Comment: @arv I've provided an update to answer.  You can add as many indicator columns as you want:) I've shown using constituents of `concatted` as well as `fruit` and added bakery for good measure.   Get to know pandas in depth,  there are so many powerful features

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Sorry, would it be possible to do the calculations for each column at a time? i.e. for each fruit  in list ['apple', 'bakery', 'bana', 'banana', 'cake', 'fruit', 'kiwi', 'tbd'] -perform the calculations,  generating 3 columns (highcalc, datecount, finalcal) for each fruit?

Comment: @arv your question seems to be evolving :) comment yesterday was about categorisation into columns,  now calcs into columns.  All possible with techniques illustrated. Approach would be do calcs on *exploded* data set then pivot it to turn into columns.  From a lot of experience with data it does not *feel* valid.  you don't have source data for each of the constituent fruits.  assuming aggregated data can be disaggregated is the source of many data quality issues

Comment: Sorry, my comment yesterday intended to say this, but I was vague, sorry.

Comment: it took my interest so I played with it....  you land up with 32 columns when starting with 4.  If you're interested update question and I'll post answer.  IMHO I prefer records to columns, but that's a preference

Comment: Since the concatted can mention more than one fruit, i thought it may be simpler to use columns; but i prefer rows too. I've updated the question but simplified by restricting the list of interested columns to ['apple' 'banana', 'orange'] only.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
# check if contains fruit, no need for loop
df['fruit'] = df['concatted'].str.contains('|'.join(fruit), regex=True)

# check proportion of "high" in each group
df['prop'] = df.groupby('date')['status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='high').sum() / len(x))

print(df)

    concatted  score        date status  fruit  prop
0  apple_bana  0.500  02/20/2010   high   True   1.0
1       apple  0.400  02/10/2010   high   True   1.0
2      banana  0.530  01/12/2010   high   True   1.0
3        kiwi  0.532  03/03/2010    low  False   0.0
4        cake  0.634  03/05/2010    low   True   0.0
```

Comment: this is slow because the transform function here is complex, it is better to calculate the size and the sum independently

Comment: Is there a way I could do this if I had multiple criteria? i.e. i have columns for apple, banana and orange which show as True if that fruit appears in the column concatted

Comment: @arv could you update the question with an example, i'll be happy to help:)

Comment: Thanks, just done it! The loop was intended so that: for each fruit in list "fruits" keep that column's fruit and then perform calculations